# How to get into VFX industry

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, video, maya

I'm 22 years old guy, from european country. I'm software engineer according to my diploma. I'm coding for 2 years now, i know few programming languages (`ruby, objective-c, javascript, python`), but last few months i started to do small tests with composing different vids (e.g. placing 3d animated objects into real world). I'm familiar with 3d modelling software such as `3dsmax` and `maya`.

After looking through different vfx studios, the problem is experience. they all want me to have 10+ years of exp in everything, which is impossible at the moment. What should i do in this case? Should i keep doing what am i doing with software coding stuff, or should i more focus on vfx, and start maybe freelancing?

Any advice is welcome.

P.S. this might be wrong hub for this kind of questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is more of a need for programmers in the gaming industry than film/vfx.

Are you interested in a programming role or a artist type role? If you want to transition, you should leverage your programming skills to get a hybrid type role like 'technical artist'.

Regardless of which industry or role you aim at, experience isn't the most important thing - that is just an excuse. Don't get me wrong, you'll need practice to get good enough, but it is not "X years in the industry".

It all comes down to your reel (artist) or demo (programming). If you can show them something that impresses them, and convince them you can recreate that in a productive manner, you'll get a job.

Ultimately they are looking for talent. There are millions of kids trying to get into these industries and only the top tiny % make it. You'll need to start by creating something, a game level, a short animation or a bunch of assets/shaders...

It is a lot of work, but with the competition you're facing for a job, you have to show that you are more determined, talented and passionate than the rest.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Perfect would be to become vfx artist without any part(if possible) of programming. I know what you mean about experience. But this is requirement in most job offers that you would have X years of exp in industry. And without this X years, they wont be even speak with you

Comment: It is also about networking. If you meet someone they can pitch you internally. I got a few guys from my course into the games industry that way. Another resource is [cgtalk](http://forums.cgsociety.org/) forums. You'll get more targeted advice and critique on VFX there. Also, companies monitor forums like that so if you can post some great work, it will get noticed. @Avdept

Comment: Thanks pal. This info is very useful. Are there any another forums related to VFX?

Comment: CgTalk is the main one. There are a lot of smaller ones, [3D Total](http://forums.3dtotal.com/), [Creative Crash](http://www.creativecrash.com/forums) and the [Autodesk Area](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-Media-and-Entertainment/ct-p/Media_and_Entertainment) come to mind. Just google 'VFX CG Forum' and you'll find a bunch.